# Microsoft Server 2003 Explorer shows duplicate local shares

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share, windows-explorer

I am new here and I could really use some advice please.

I am having a problem with our file server. When I try to browse the shared folders using explorer, several of the shared folders all appear to have the same name. Whenever I attempt to rename one of the affected folders, all the affected folders name also change.

Our File Server is Windows Server 2003 R2.

I am logged on directly to the server using remote desktop.

When I open the folder all is as it should be, the proper content is there and the address bar displays the correct folder name and path. The share names are correct, so everything that needs to access the shared folder/files can do so.

Also when I browse to the folder using the command-line all it as it should be there too.

The only issue seems to be the incorrect display name when browsing using explorer.

Can anyone offer any advice or help as to how to resolve this issue please? It would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you current on all Windows Updates?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the "strange" behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Try logging on to the physical console and looking at it. If it's normal then the problem is some anomaly in the RDP protocol driver.

Comment: I have some Windows updates pending, the system is waiting for a restart. Should I restart? 

Here is a link to a screenshot of the odd behaviour

http://i899.photobucket.com/albums/ac197/dashnitro/screenshot2.gif

I will try logging on to the physical console and let you know how I get on.

Thanks for your advice and help guys

Comment: I have tried logging on to the physical server and the fault is also occuring there too. 

Im not sure if I want to install the updates as a rogue update last year renamed the c drive on our exchange server and no one could get any email for 2 days. Since then we have been very reluctant to install any updates.

Comment: Hi folks. Quick update, I have discovered all affected shared folders are for users using a windows 7 machine. I think it may have something to do with running a script which redirects the users my documents folder to a share on the server. This is the shared folder which is affected. any thoughts?